# Merging arrays but getting Array index out of bound exception

Tags: java

I am trying to merge two sorted arrays, that is check is `A[i]` is less than `B[j]` then create an Array `C[k]` to store the new array of merged arrays, my problem however is I am getting a  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` How can I solve this error:

The Last two for loops are to check if we are done comparing A and B and some elements are left move them to C. Here I am assuming A and B is sorted. m and n is size of the Arrays.

Any help will be appreciated Code below:

public class MergeArrays {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //given two arrays merge them

    int a [] = {2,8,15,18,19,20};
    int b [] = {5,9,12,17};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(a,b,5,3)));
}

private static int[] mergeArrays(int[] A, int[] B, int m, int n) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i =1;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 1;
    int C [] = new int [1];

    while(i <= m && j <= n) {

        if(A[i] < B[j]) {

            C[k++] = A[i++];
        }else {
            C[k++] = B[j++];
        }
    }

    for(; i<=m ; i++) {
        C[k++] = A[i];
    }
    for(; j <= n; j++) {
        C[k++] = B[j];
    }

    return C;
}
```

}

Comment: Indeed pstz duder, the counter starts at nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int C [] = new int [8];
```

Please provide proper array length in above line. You are providing array length to 1 and k++/i++ values are exceeding to 1 so it is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't resetting your counters before entering your for loops.

edit: You are also checking if your current counter is less than or equals 5 for example which will throw you an index out of bounds error anyway because arrays start at index 0. But you also try to reach for the incremented index within your brackets "A[i++]" which is going to exceed the index limit too.

edit2: Your "C[]" is also initalized with the size of [1] which means it has following indexes: {0,1}. You set your "k" counter to 1 but once you reach for an index in your "C[]" array you are putting k incremented: "C[k++]", now you are trying to reach for index 2 which doesn't exist. Rewrite your code. I advice you to use inner counters and just use your_array_name.length() to get your array length. eg. for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes you are doing, just I'll point out so you can fix it.

- Array 'C' size should be equal to Length of array 'A' + Length of array 'B.
- In Java, array index start with 0 and end with Array length -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your can create class like this,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //given two arrays merge them

        int a[] = {2, 8, 15, 18, 19, 20};
        int b[] = {5, 9, 12, 17};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(a, b, a.length, b.length)));
    }

    private static int[] mergeArrays(int[] A, int[] B, int m, int n) {

        int[] C = null;
        if (m > n) {
            C = A;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (A[i] < B[i]) {
                    C[i] = B[i];
                }
            }
        } else {
            C = B;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (A[i] > B[i]) {
                    C[i] = A[i];
                }


            }



        }
        return C;
    }
```